# Cant figure out how to initialize a tableView in Swift

Tags: swift

Im trying to figure out where my loop is coming from and I suspect that this line of code may not work as I think it should.
So I installed cocoapod in **Objective C** to my **Swift** project and I need to initialize a tableManager

Here is how its done in Objective C

```
self.flabbyTableManager = [[BRFlabbyTableManager alloc] initWithTableView:self.tableView];
```

Here is what I "translated" it into in Swift

```
let flabbyTableManager = BRFlabbyTableManager(tableView: self.tableView)
```

When I run the program it doesn't give me any exception or errors its just pointing to an AppDelegate class and saying EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I really don't know what can cause that. Im a fairly new to Swift, but I have never encountered a problem using pods before. I have my bridging file with everything imported.

I don't know if calling an initializer named initWithTableView() like I did (just creating a new instance and passing a tableView as a parameter) is going to do it right.

Comment: Please put a better title on your question.  What is your actual question?  Put that in the title.

Comment: @RobertHarvey better?

Comment: hello , did you work and run BRFlabbyTableManager in swift ? I am getting sigbart crashing for this line `let cell:BRFlabbyTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! BRFlabbyTableViewCell`

can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct code in swift:

```
self.flabbyTableManager = BRFlabbyTableManager(tableView: self.tableView)
```

As for why your app is crashing, that could be anything.